# Alchemy CMS - Admin UI - Editor - Show in all page area

Tags: editor, admin, show, alchemy-cms

In `Alchemy CMS` admin user interface the `editor area` occupies the right side of the page.

The left side is occupied by the previewer.

There are cases where we work with a big text and we would like to have **all the page area for the editor**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no full screen mode for the whole elements panel on the right, but the Tinymce editor used in richtext areas has a full screen mode. The button is on the right of the lower toolbar row.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply...
but
this button does not use all the page area.
It utilises the right side of the screen...
and this is not very convenient....

Comment: I see. This should not be the case. Could you please open an issue on the bug tracker?